# Querying an embedded document in an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this subdocument embedded in an array:

```
 company:{
    products:[
      { vehicle: "Toyota", Model: "Camry" },
      { vehicle: "Honda", Model: "Civic" },
      { vehicle: "Honda", Model: "Accord" },
      { vehicle: "Mercedes", Model: "vboot" },
    ]
 }
```

How do I select the vehicle that matches only

```
{vehicle:'Honda', Model:'Civic'}
```

Thus:

```
company:{
    products:[         
      { vehicle: "Honda", Model: "Civic" },
    ]
 }
```

Comment: You need to use `$elemMatch`, why vehicle array has no key?

Answer (score 2):

Given a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ....,
    "company" : [ 
        {
            "vehicle" : "Toyota",
            "Model" : "Camry"
        }, 
        {
            "vehicle" : "Honda",
            "Model" : "Civic"
        }, 
        {
            "vehicle" : "Honda",
            "Model" : "Accord"
        }, 
        {
            "vehicle" : "Mercedes",
            "Model" : "vboot"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following query uses the `$elemMatch` *query operator* to find only those documents having `vehicle:'Honda' and Model:'Civic'`:

```
db.collection.find(
    { company: { $elemMatch: { vehicle: 'Honda', Model: 'Civic' } } }
)
```

If you only want to return the first element in the company array having `vehicle:'Honda' and Model:'Civic'` then you should use the `$elemMatch` *projection operator*:

```
db.collection.find(
    // only find documents which have a company entry having vehicle=Honda and model=Civic
    { company: { $elemMatch: { vehicle: 'Honda', Model: 'Civic' } } }, 

    // for the documents found by the previous clause, only return the first element
    // in the company array which has vehicle=Honda and model=Civic
    { company: { $elemMatch: { vehicle: 'Honda', Model: 'Civic' } } }
)

// returns:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a79613f85c9cec3a82c902c"),
    "company" : [ 
        {
            "vehicle" : "Honda",
            "Model" : "Civic"
        }
    ]
}
```

From the docs:

- The [`$elemMatch` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) ...

> The `$elemMatch` operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

- The [`$elemMatch` projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) ...

> The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an `<array>` field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition.

Comment: thanks glyching for your reply but i use $elemMatch it select both vehicle with model 'Civic and Accord' instead of just 'Civic' as i wish

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to $elemMatch on the $project. Can you please update your answer with an example document showing **exactly** what response you want your query to return. Without that anyone attempting to answer this question has to guess what your requirements are.

Comment: @yaxx I have updated the answer to include usage of the `$elemMatch` projection operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` keyword needs to be used for the specific element:

```
db.company.find({vehicle:"Honda",Model:"Civic"})
```

Comment: that did not work because the object is nested within an array